# How do I prevent random jquery toggle?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a list item I'm using for mobile navigation. It looks like this:

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Menu item 1</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Menu item 2</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Menu item 3</a>
      <div id="submenu-wrap">
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#">SubMenu item 1</a></li>
          <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#">SubMenu item 2</a></li>
        </ul> 
      </div>
    </li> 
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Menu item 4</a></li> 
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Menu item 5</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Menu item 6</a>
      <div id="submenu-wrap">
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#">SubMenu item 3</a></li>
          <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#">SubMenu item 4</a></li>
        </ul> 
      </div>    
    </li>     
  </ul> 
</div>
```

I have the submenus (ul) hidden and only appears when a jquery toggle trigger is clicked.

Here's what my jquery looks like:

```
$('#submenu-wrap').on('click',function(){
     $('.submenu').slideToggle(); 
});
```

Here's what my css looks like:
    #submenu-wrap {
        position: relative!important;
    }

```
#submenu-wrap:after {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #555555;
    cursor: pointer;
    content: "\f078";
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: -30px;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

I use the div that wraps the submenu (#submenu-wrap) to toggle the submenu. 
It's works perfectly well.

The problem I'm having is that when the trigger is clicked, it opens all the hidden submenus (ul). I want it to open only the next submenu. That's to say, open only the submenu that it wraps. Each trigger should open its own submenu.

I could really use some help here...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `id` must be *unique*

Comment: the solution has already been offered, but i wanted to just share a philosophy I've developed: never use the word "random." because whatever is happening is probably happening due to a series of programmatic choices you've made. which means that you can probably track down the decisions and make different ones. calling a thing "random" removes your perceived power to change a thing. carry on and stay strong, fellow coder! don't let the robots win!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As dm295 mentioned, `id` values must be unique. `submenu-wrap` should be a `class` instead of an `id`.

Given that change, it sounds like you need to search for `.submenu` elements that are children of the clicked element:

```
$('.submenu-wrap').on('click',function(){
    $(this).find('.submenu').slideToggle(); 
});
```